Trying to create a generic HTML template that renders a set of questions under topic headings based on context from views.py
Edited - Test Code or lists
Created quick page to printout the Topic and associated questions
html:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<head>
   <title>Resilience</title>
</head>
<body>
   <h1>Test</h1>
   <p>{{questions_by_topic}}
       {% for topic in questions_by_topic%}
       <li> {{topic}}</li>
           {% for question in questions_by_topic%}
           <li> {{question}}</li>
       {% endfor %}
       {% endfor %}
</body>
</html>

This renders the following webpage:
Test

defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {<Topic: Risk Assessment and Planning>: ['Conducts annual risk assessments and identifies key risks and mitigation action', 'Identifies key risks and mitigation actions', 'Uses risk assessment to set business continuity policy and objectives compatible with the organization’s strategic directio'], <Topic: Oversight>: ['Provides the necessary resources for accomplishing business continuity objectives', 'Integrates business continuity plans into business processes', 'Communicates the importance of effective business continuity and adhering to requirements', 'Provides direction and support to staff to drive business continuity effectiveness'], <Topic: Execution and Improvement>: ['Conduct annual test of business continuity plans', 'Promotes continual improvement by incorporating lessens learned from periodic testing or event reviews', 'Ensures intended business continuity outcomes are achieved']})

Risk Assessment and Planning
Risk Assessment and Planning
Oversight
Execution and Improvement
Oversight
Risk Assessment and Planning
Oversight
Execution and Improvement
Execution and Improvement
Risk Assessment and Planning
Oversight
Execution and Improvement

If I use:
 {% for question in questions_by_topic%}
        <li> {{question.question_by_topic}}</li>

It changes the lists rendered to:
 - Risk Assessment and Planning
 -
 -
 -
 -Oversight
 -
 -
 -
 -Execution and Improvement
 -
 -
 -

similarly:
            {% for question in questions%}
        <li> {{question}}</li>

renders all 10 questions under each topic, not just the ones associated with the topic
EDIT" Added models.py
    # Create your models here.
class Question_Answers(models.Model):
    value = models.IntegerField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    q_id = models.CharField(max_length=10, default="XX")

    def __str__(self):
         return f"{self.q_id} value is {self.value}"


class Questions(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    q_id = models.CharField(max_length=10, default="XX")
    topic_id = models.CharField(max_length=10, default="XX")

    def __str__(self):
         return f"{self.q_id} is question {self.question}"

class Question_Comments(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    comments = models.CharField(max_length=1000, default="No comment")

    def __str__(self):
         return f"{self.name} comments are {self.comments}"
      
class Topic(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    topic_id = models.CharField(max_length=10, default="XX")

    def __str__(self):
         return f"{self.name} is {self.ctopic_id}"

I have several areas, i.e. Leadership, operations, etc., each of which has a set of topics and questions associated with it.   Leadership, for example, has 3 topics, each with a different set and number of questions.
I am trying to create a general questions.html template where the views.py can then fit with the specific area, topics, questions, etc. for that area.  I provide the topics, separate question sets for each topic via context when rendering the page for that area.
I am trying to avoid hardcoding each page by looping through each topic and using the question set for that topic.
I tested the code by hardcoding 1 question set and seeing if the table render properly, and it does except of course the questions are repeated under each topic.
However, when I set the outer loop to loop through the topics with each unique questions set using variables, none of the questions appear. The page just renders the topics with no errors.
Here is the code snippet  that works but reuses the questions:
  <tbody>
{% for m in categories %}
    <td colspan="7">{{ m }}</td>
    
        {% for key, value in questions1.items %}
        <tr>
            <td class="question">{{ value }} </td>
                {% for n in nchoices %}
                    {% if n == 0 %} 
                    <td>
                    
                        <input name={{ key }} type="radio" value={{ n }}  id="{{ key }}_{{n}}"/> Not Sure
                
                    </td>
                    {% else %}
                    <td>
                    
                    <input name={{ key }} type="radio" value={{ n }}  id="{{ key }}_{{n}}"/>{{ n }}
            
                    </td>
                    {% endif%}
                {% endfor %}
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
</table>

<h4>Enter any comments about your responses to the questions</h4>
<textarea name="{{ textname }}"></textarea>

<input type="submit">

views.py snippet (edited to remove non essential code):
def test(request):
        questions1 = {"L_Q1": "Conducts annual risk assessments and identifies key risks and mitigation actions"}
        
        questions2 =  {"L_Q4":"Provides the necessary resources for accomplishing business continuity objectives"}
        
        questions3 =  {"L_Q8": "Conduct annual test of business continuity plans"}
        
        nchoices = [0,1,2,3,4,5]

        categories = ["Risk Assessment and Planning", "Oversight", "Execution and Improvement"]
        
        questions = ["questions1","questions2","questions3"]

        textname= ["L_Text"]
        
        context = {
            "questions": questions,
            "questions1": questions1,
            "questions2": questions2,
            "questions3": questions3,
            "categories": categories,
            "nchoices": nchoices,
            "textname": textname
        }

        if request.method == "POST":
            return render(request, "leadershipresults.html", context)
        else:

            return render(request, "questions.html", context)

I tried adding loops inside the outer loop to select each question set but that's when it fails to render the questions, for example:
{% for m in categories %}
    <td colspan="7">{{ m }}</td>
    {% for x in questions %}
            {% for key, value in x.items %}
            <tr>
                <td class="question">{{ value }} </td>
                    {% for n in nchoices %}
                        {% if n == 0 %} 
                        <td>
                        
                            <input name={{ key }} type="radio" value={{ n }}  id="{{ key }}_{{n}}"/> Not Sure
                    
                        </td>
                        {% else %}
                        <td>
                        
                        <input name={{ key }} type="radio" value={{ n }}  id="{{ key }}_{{n}}"/>{{ n }}
                
                        </td>
                        {% endif%}
                    {% endfor %}
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}

Is it possible to use a variable to identify which list to use select the proper question set?

Does each category have its own questions?If yes then use dictionary where categories are keys and questions in value as list

They do, with varying amounts of questions per category.  I should be able to use the key (category) in the outer loop, then loop through questions category values) with an inner loop using a dictionary of question ids and a final loop to assign values to each radio button.

Post your models so that i can give you complete code for loops

I've posted above.  Right now I hardcoded the dictionaries

Django by default has id.Can I remove the redundant ids or do they have a special purpose?

No special purpose I added them I as secondary keys to link between tables for specific questions and answers; but then again the last time I did and Sql was over 30 years ago...

I renamed the django models to follow PEP guides.See here
# type: ignore
from django.db import models


class Topic(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
   

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name}"


class Question(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)  # THis is probably useless

    topic = models.ForeignKey(
        Topic, on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )  # Django will store this as topic_id on database

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name} is question {self.question}"


class Answer(models.Model):
    value = models.IntegerField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    # q_id = models.CharField(max_length=10, default="XX")  # USed foreignkey instead
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.question} value is {self.value}"


class Comment(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    comments = models.CharField(max_length=1000, default="No comment")
    question = models.ForeignKey(
        Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )  # Use One to one if a question has one answer

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name} comments are {self.comments}"

The simple way to get the Questions and respective topics would be
questions = Question.objects.select_related('topic').all()
#Then create a dict
from collections import defaultdict
questions_by_topic = defaultdict(list)#If not topic in dict then it will create it with empty list as value
for question in questions:
    questions_by_topic[question.topic].append(question.question)

#You can then use the dict in html as so
for topic, questions in questions_by_topic.items():
    print(f"Topic: {topic.name}")
    for question in questions:
        print(f" - {question}")


Thanks.  I'll give it a try.  One question - since Comment is tied to a specific topic or question, but to the Area teh topics fall under, I need to add another class Area use Area as the ForeignKey

In the above Comment class,comments are tied to a question.You can add the Area as a foreign key if it is a separate model

Thanks,  What is the comment #type: ignore?

I also changed Comments' FK to Area since it is uniquely tied to an area, not a question; as there is only 1 comment field per page.  I had used q_id to identify answers to questions so I could use it to get all the answers to one question for analysis, but reverse lookup from question should do that a well, correct?

Topic is One to one with Area, however if I add a OneToONEField or FK I get  "impossible to add a non-nullable field 'area' to topic without specifying a default" using same code as in comment area = models.ForeignKey(         Area, on_delete=models.CASCADE or area = models.OneToOneField(         Area, on_delete=models.CASCADE

I got the models and dictionary working, but when I try to use the variables in HTML nothing populates in the table - no radio buttons or topic headers.  The dictionary prints properly in terminal. Added code above

About #type: ignore I use mypy so the  comment on top of the file is to tell mypy to skip checking types,you can Ignore that.Regarding the foreignKey you have to provide the value when creating an instance

Depends on how you have passed the context to the template..You might want to check the values reach there first using {{ dictionary }} if you can see th dict then proceed with looping if not check it back..If you are using class-based-views you will want to override the get_context_method

It appears the dictionary is coming through, and I can iterate against topic but not question.  Code and output above.

Hello have you solved your problem.Its good that you can see the topics.Have you tried printing the context before rendering to templates as in that way you can get a clear picture on what is being sent to the templates

I have - I wound up simply breaking each ste of questions by topic sepereatly and rendering them that way.  Thanks for your help.  I've Post date code above.
